# How to check if IE for inline css

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Hi simple problem really.

I have a search box function and in all browsers the button sit a little low so I have added 5px at bottom. However with IE it then 5px too high. so i have seen and tried the following. `<![if !IE]>bottom:5px;<![endif]>`

This obviously isnt working. I am trying/wanting to do this in "in-line CSS"

Is this possible?

Comment: is it possible to do this Via using PHP, am better at PHP.

Comment: Why do you want to use inline css?

Comment: is quite a minor little change and there is a huge amount of css on total project. am after an easier fix really.

Comment: So there aren't any classes or anything you can use?

Comment: could u just show us the CSS code?

Comment: potentially. can you explain how this can be done in css, as it needs to be an if !IE do the 5px?

Comment: style="position: relative; bottom:5px; float: left;" this is the simple css that applies to the box im talking about

Comment: Don't add them directly to the element. Use classes. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to run an IE stylesheet then you can use conditional comments in your `<head>` tag to add styles.

```
    <!--[if IE]>
       <style>
           .your_class {
               bottom: 5px;
           }
       </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

I'd run an IE stylesheet myself but if you don't want to then you can do it this way.

Have a read up on conditional comments - http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score -1):

```
#searchbar {
position: relative;
bottom:5px;
^bottom:5px;
_bottom:5px;
float: left;
}
```

This will do for all versions of i.e above 6. Just put this --  ^bottom:5px; -- above this -- _bottom:5px; -- .... and this will do the trick.